# Table in ERB with weekday names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am very new to Ruby/Rails and just I am trying to find the most elegant way to do a table in ERB where the columns are the weekday and the rows are each record for a given model. The concept itself is easy and I can probably do it through a bunch of manual code, but I would like to leverage as much rails/erb magic as possible. To be more specific, here is what I have defined.

- A model that lists all users
- A model that lists a single status for each user for a given date (each user can only have one status for a given date: say 'on' or 'off')

I want a view that lists all the users in a table with their status for that week. Eg:

```
       Mon | Tue | ... | Fri
User1   on | off | ... |
User2  off |     | ... |
```

A couple things to note:
- (as I already mentioned) A user can only have one status per day
- A user may not have any status for a given day
- No columns for Sat/Sun
- The table will always show the full current week, even if the day is on Tue (ie. in that case the Wed .. Fri entries will just be blank).

Now, again, I am sure I can write a bunch of erb code to do this all manually, but was hoping to use some rails magic. Any pointers or help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could always do something like:

```
@monday = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week
7.times do |x|
  @days << x.days.since(@monday)
end
```

Then loop through @days in your view.

You could print the date, or just the day in hour table rows.  Useful in that you can also look up your users status using that date.